# Store all filenames from a folder into a vector

Tags: c++, winapi

This the code. Everthing works fine, but when i try to cout for example:

```
cout << getAllSongs("path\\*")[1]
```

the output is nothing, it dosn't show anything

```
vector<string> getAllSongs(string path) {
    // can queue up up to 1000 melodii
    vector<string> songList(1000);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    string all = path;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(all.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << hFind;
        cout << "there is a handle problem";
        exit(-1);
    }
    else do {
        //cout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl; this works
        songList.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);

    return songList;    
}
```

Comment: `songList(1000);` it creates 1000 empty string, so `getAllSongs("..")[1]` shows you one of them. `[1001]` may work.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with files. Run this in the debugger and examine what happens step by step.

Comment: problem solved, thank you @rafix07

Comment: @kraneqq If you found the issue, you should post your solution as an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what is actually in the folder, you are always pre-filling the vector with 1000 empty strings, and then adding filenames starting at index 1000. So the string at `vector[1]` is always empty.

Try something more like this instead:

```
vector<string> getAllSongs(string path) {
    // can queue up up to 1000 melodii

    //vector<string> songList(1000); // <-- DO NOT create 1000 empty strings!
    vector<string> songList;
    songList.reserve(1000); // <-- DO THIS instead!

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(path.c_str(), &FindFileData); // <-- use the ANSI function explicitly!
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) { // <-- ADD error checking...
            cout << "there is a problem with the search!";
        }
    }
    else {
        do {
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0) { // <-- ADD type checking...
                //cout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl; this works
                songList.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &FindFileData)); // <-- use the ANSI function explicitly!

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) { // <-- ADD error checking...
            cout << "there is a problem with the search!";
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    return songList;    
}
```

```
vector<string> songs = getAllSongs("path\\*");
if (!songs.empty()) { // <-- ADD error checking...
    cout << songs[0]; // <-- ONLY non-empty filenames exist in the vector now!
}
```

Comment: i don't need anymore replies, it was a problem on my thinking, i solved it thanks